# Change Value From Select Option in Angular

Tags: angular, html

What I want to accomplish is when the Value of StartHour is changed (When the startHour is Higher than the value from EndHour) EndHour Value must change to StartHour plus one hour.

```
<div class="startHourSelection">
    <label *ngIf="startHourSelection">Begin uur</label>
        <div *ngIf="startHourSelection" class="select">    
            <select id="starthour" (change)="onSelectStartHour($event.target.value)" [disabled]="parentIsLoading">
                <option
                    *ngFor="let Hour of startHours; let i = index"
                    value="{{Hour}}"
                    [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">
                    {{Hour}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="endHourSelection">
    <label *ngIf="endHourSelection">Eind uur</label>
        <div *ngIf="endHourSelection" class="select"> 
            <select id="endHour" (change)="onSelectEndHour($event.target.value)" [disabled]="parentIsLoading">
                <option
                    *ngFor="let Hour of endHours; let i = index"
                    value="{{Hour}}"
                    [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">
                    {{Hour}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Component:

The @Input of both is on false, I also know i have all the hours as strings instead of DATE I'm not sure if i have to convert it

```
@Output() selectStartHour = new EventEmitter<string>(); // when a strathour is selected
@Output() selectEndHour = new EventEmitter<string>(); // when a strathour is selected

startHours = [
    '00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00',
    '13:00', '14:00',  '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'
];

endHours = [
    '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00',
    '13:00', '14:00',  '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '24:00'

];

onSelectStartHour(startHour: string) {
        this.selectStartHour.emit(startHour);
    }

    onSelectEndHour(endHour: string) {
        this.selectEndHour.emit(endHour);
    }
```

Comment: Please post a sample demo online

Comment: Please post onSelectStartHour  method code and what is the initial value of endHours and startHours?

Comment: Done :) thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

**HTML file changes**

Add `ngModel` in both select element.

Ex:

Start Hours select :  `<select id="starthour" .... [(ngModel)]="startHour">`

End Hours select :  `<select id="endHour" .... [(ngModel)]="endHour">`

**TS files changes**

add condition code in `onSelectStartHour()` method and change `endHours` value.

Comment: let me know if you need any help. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I'm stuck on the part of how to treat ngmodel in TS. Do i have to declare endHour, starthour on my TS as type Any and then compare it in onSelectEndHour?

Comment: yes.. or instead of 12:00 use 12 only and append :00 while you display value in option.